# Reference request: structure of unitary representations of $\mathbb{Z}$

Tags: reference-request, representation-theory, hilbert-spaces, abelian-groups

Let $H$ be a separable Hilbert space and $(H,\pi)$ a unitary representation of $\mathbb{Z}$.

I'm looking for a reference/some hints to help me answer the following two basic questions:

**Question 1:** Can we decompose $H$ as a countable direct sum $\oplus_{k\in\mathbb{Z}}H_k$, where each $H_k=\mathbb{C}v_k$ is a one-dimensional representation of $\mathbb{Z}$, for some $v_k\in H$?

**Question 2:** Would the answer change if $\pi\colon H\to GL(H)$ instead of $U(H)$?

Comment: What do you mean with a unitary representation if the codomain is not $U(H)?$

Comment: @QuantumSpace For question 2, I meant what happens with non-unitary representations, whether they behave the same way as unitary ones.

Comment: This I don't know. I never use such representations, and the question is better answered by an algebraist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any book that treats unitary representations should contain the answer to these facts, e.g. Folland's "A course in abstract harmonic analysis"

Let me try to answer question 1. We are given a unitary representation $\pi: \mathbb{Z}\to U(H)$. Any unitary representation of locally compact group is unitarily equivalent with a direct sum of irreducible ones, so
$$\pi \sim \bigoplus_{i \in I}\pi_i$$
where $\pi_i: \mathbb{Z}\to U(H_i)$ are irreducible unitary representations. However, since $\mathbb{Z}$ is abelian, the irreducible representations are one-dimensional, so that $H_i \cong \mathbb{C}$. Hence, it is clear that

$$H \cong \bigoplus_{i \in I} H_i \cong \bigoplus_{i \in I} \mathbb{C}$$
as desired. More generally, the same is true for $\mathbb{Z}$ replaced by any abelian group.

In other words, $H$ decomposes as a direct sum of one-dimensional invariant subspaces.